# C# Application Detect internet connectivity continually

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Window-Form Application connecting to a server for database updates. When application starts, I connect to the internet. On the Form I show a green Button, which shows internet connectivity on Load-Event. If there is no connectivity then it shows a red button.

```
public bool check()
{
    try
    {
        Ping myPing = new Ping();
        String host = "google.com";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        int timeout = 1000;
        PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
        PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
        return (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

I want this button change it's color automatic, when ever it lost it's connectivity from internet or when internet come back.

How i can implement this?

Comment: Use a timer to call your `Check` method every X milliseconds

Comment: You can use a ' Timer'. And `on timer.Tick` you can insert the code to update the button color.

Comment: I can do that but is there inbuilt class or  any another method to perform this action automatic rather then timer  keep running

Comment: I'd suggest that you implement a task to check out the connection availability.

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged);
            Console.WriteLine("Its main");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsAvailable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("its event");
            }
            
        }
    } I have tried this network change class but does not work